# howto create an Ajax Popup Form and submit the form

Tags: jquery, ajax, popup

I like to request a ajax-popup bij clicking on a link with variable. The popup will show some date requested from the server. After submit the data will be checked on the server and send a responce back. Depending on the responce, new content will be showed in the popup. The user can close the popup afterwards.

I have searched a while for a tutorial or example, but i can't find any.

Who can give me an example or suggestion to startup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check into the [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) widget. It can do what you need. You just put the controls, text, etc into a DIV, and then invoke the method to pop the dialog. Since the code is in a div, you can update it dynamically with the results of ajax calls as needed.